# Get all unique combinations of values from two tables where a 3rd value is equivalent google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've got 2 tables and on a third table I want to have all unique combinations of table2.a, table1.b where table1.c==table2.c

`SELECT table2.a, table1.b FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE table1.c=table2.c`

In sql I would be using inner join or join (I think) but I can't seem to find a way to do this using google sheets query()

It doesn't need to join the actual keys together like I have in table3.a I have already added an arrayformula to handle that. The prefered output would be a 2d array that I can fill in table3.b:c

table1

```
a b c
  4 7
  5 8
  6 9
```

table2

```
a b c
1   7
2   8
3   9
```

table3 (wanted output)

```
a  b  c
14 1  4 
25 2  5
36 3  6
```

Comment: [Cross-posted on Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100700), please avoid cross-posting as it splits potential answers between sites.

Comment: answered on the Web Apps page
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100700/get-all-unique-combinations-of-values-from-two-tables-where-a-3rd-value-is-equiv